Failed scipy install using pip on Windows [Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully]
I managed to install a few popular python packages using pip in Windows, (more speicifically using the command py -m pip install <packagename>).
Packages like numpy, pandas, matplotlib, pyqt5, etc. had no problem installing, but some packages like scipy and scikit-learn give errors.
Collecting scipy
  Using cached scipy-1.10.1.tar.gz (42.4 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1

╰─> [14 lines of output]
      + meson setup --prefix=C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32 C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-

install-kcwepnco\scipy_545e8a24382142de9b0a2e3bbeb71b01 C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-kcwepnco

\scipy_545e8a24382142d
e9b0a2e3bbeb71b01\.mesonpy-k7npgzdq\build --native-file=C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-kcwepnco

\scipy_545e8a24382142de9b0a2e3bbeb71b01\.mesonpy-native-file.ini -Ddebug=false -Doptimization=2
      The Meson build system
      Version: 1.4.1
      Source dir: C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-kcwepnco\scipy_545e8a24382142de9b0a2e3bbeb71b01
      Build dir: C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-kcwepnco\scipy_545e8a24382142de9b0a2e3bbeb71b01\.mesonpy-
k7npgzdq\build
      Build type: native build
      Project name: SciPy
      Project version: 1.10.1
      C compiler for the host machine: cl (msvc 12.00.8168 "Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 

12.00.8168 for 80x86")
      C linker for the host machine: link link 6.00.8168

      ..\..\meson.build:1:0: ERROR: None of values ['c++14'] are supported by the C++ compiler. Possible values are 

['none', 'none', 'c++11', 'vc++11']

A full log can be found at...
[end of output]
...

 note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

I have no idea what is going on.
My OS is Windows 8 and Python verson is 3.8 .
I upgraded pip and also did try:
py -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel

But still no luck after that.
I am relatively new to python, so a detailed or easy solution using pip will be greatly appreciated.

The direct issue that you are seeing is, that scipy has a C-backend which pip is trying to compile, but finds that your compiler does not support options needed to do so:
 ERROR: None of values ['c++14'] are supported by the C++ compiler

Usually, for this kind of library (and especially on windows), it can get quite complex to compile them yourself, which is why there are often pre-compiled versions available. If you look on https://pypi.org/project/scipy/1.10.1/#files you can see

The "source distribution", which is the .tar.gz file
"Binary distributions" - the .whl files which each have a tag for OS/python version, for example scipy-1.10.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl means scipy, version 1.10.1, CPython 3.9, windows x64

You have a 32 bit variant of python, but if you check the linked list of available files for scipy 1.10.1, then there are no .whl files for windows that are not x64. This will not only make trouble with scipy, but also other packages, as supporting 32 bit python versions is not standard anymore.
My recommendation is to uninstall your current python version and install a 64 bit version instead. If possible, also consider using a more recent version of python.

Thanks, so I need to upgrade my python version. But I want to ask if every package that I have installed so far can be kept working just fine in any way if, say, I upgrade to 3.9 or above.
Or do I have to reinstall everything?

OK, I just uninstalled Python 3.8 and updated it with 3.10 64bit. Now it seems to work fine. I am just wondering if I can reinstall 3.8 32bit without giving it to path and not  associating it with any file extension and keep both 3.8 and 3.10. Anyway, thanks for the solution.

for your first question: no, every package needs to be installed again when you change python versions. for your second question: yes you can have multiple python versions in one computer, you just have to be careful to not mix them up. FOr that, environment managers like conda are a great tool to have different python versions clearly seperated

As you are running an older version of Python and windows you might face a lot of issues, consider upgrading, the above issue is also caused due to outdated environments.

OK, I just uninstalled Python 3.8 and updated it with 3.10 64bit. Now it seems to work fine. Thanks for the suggestion.

The stable release of scipy requires: Python >=3.9 and also the stable release of scikit-learn requires: Python >=3.9.
You can upgrade your Python to fix this error. Also do note that extended support for Python 3.8 will end on October 2024.

The latest stabel release of scipy requires python>=3.9, older versions, 1.10.1 which OP is trying to install  does not, see https://pypi.org/project/scipy/1.10.1

OK, I will try upgrading python. I am just worried if that might create new problems. Also, many packages that are working just fine will have to be reinstalled I guess. And need to make sure I add it to path.

OK, I just uninstalled Python 3.8 and updated it with 3.10 64bit. Now it seems to work fine. Thanks for the suggestion.
